# Importing interchange file (.e00) in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: import, arcgis-pro, e00

I have ArcGIS Pro 1.31 and I found on ESRI website that the "import from E00" tool is no longer available in ArcGIS Pro.

So what's the solution if you want to work with interchange files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no conversion tools in ArcGIS Pro to convert coverages. However, if you have ArcGIS Pro, you should have ArcMap. You can convert them there to a featureclass and use that inside ArcGIS Pro.

There is a little more information about this here - https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177435